# WPF - Binding between usercontrol

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I have a user control (say A) with two ContentPresenter each binded to another usercontrol (say B and C).

In one of the two UserControl(say B) I have a listBox of MyItem.

```
         <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyItem}">
```

MyItem code:

```
Public Class MyItem
   Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

   Private m_Name As Integer
   Public Property Name As Integer
      Get
      Return m_Name 
      End Get
      Set(value As Integer)
         m_Name = value
      End Set
   End Property

   ...

End Class
```

In the other one(say C) I have TextBoxes that I want to bind to SelectedItem properties(say MyItem.Name).

```
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name}"/>
```

Is it possible in some way? Because I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying is close to impossible.

Bind the textbox text to some property in view model c.  Bind the list selected item to some property in view model b.

Emit an event with argument as the `Name` value as string when selected item is changed. Handle event in viewmodel c and update the textbox text with the received Name argument.

This would do the trick.

Another possible way is to create b and c view model instances in A viewmodel and update cviewmodelinstance.TextboxPropertyName when bviewmodelinstance.selectedListItem property is changed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm very interested in the second method you mentioned because I almost create B and C viewmodel in A viewmodel. But I don't understand how to update a property when another is changed. Can you please write an example of the textbox binding(in XAML) in this case? Thank you

Comment: I don't know vb actually. Just bind to string property in corresponding view  model. Subscribe to viewmodelinstance.propertychanged in parent view model. On propertychanged check the property name using **e**.  If property name == your required property, set the string bound to text box text property.